# Wordpress posts are not showing in categories but showed after update

Tags: wordpress

I have built a wordpress theme and import data via phpMyAdmin. Imported data was exported from a wordpress multisite and it has 2,354 posts.

All the posts are now showing on main page but when I go to any category it shows an empty page. Even though that category has posts.

The method I discover of showing those posts is to manually hit update button in the dashboard and it shows on that category page.

I have tried bulk post update, run SQL query but all in vein.

Can anyone help me on this one? :)

Thanks, 
Omer

Comment: This might help: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/lost-categories-in-import-of-wordpresscom

Comment: Better late than never. I just had a similar problem, and I solved it by rewriting my permalink rules.

Comment: Go to wordpress settings and rebuild your permalink, should solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to /wp-admin and then settings -> Permalinks and hit save. (Worked last time i had this problem)

If that doesn't work, try to add following line to your wp-config.php and see if you get any useful debug-information

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```